# Why do the buttons not appear in the tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently trying to learn tkinter. I do not understand why the buttons I defined do not appear in this code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):
        def __init__(self, master=None):
            Frame.__init__(self, master)
            self.master = master



            button1 = Button(self, text="Exit", width=12, command=self.clickButton1)

            button1.grid(row=0)

            button2 = Button(self, text="Test", width=12, command=self.clickButton2)

            button2.grid(row=1)

        def clickButton1(self):
            exit()

        def clickButton2(self):
            print("Nice")

root = Tk()
app = Window(root)
root.title("Tkinter window")

root.mainloop()
```

When I don't use a class it works. Like this for example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

button1 = Button(root, text="Works!!!")
button1.grid(row=0)

button2 = Button(root, text="Also works!!!")
button2.grid(row=1)

root.mainloop()
´´´
```

Comment: It is because you don't call any layout function on `app`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the class creates a frame, and then puts widgets inside the frame. However, you never add the frame to the window so the widgets inside the frame will be invisible.

You need to make sure and call `pack`, `grid`, or `place` on the instance of `Window`, just like you do with any other widget.

```
app = Window(root)
app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Comment: Okay it seems this is the better answer thank you. It makes sense now why it didn't work.